# Three.js and Angular4 with a JSONLoader

Tags: javascript, json, angular, three.js

Im trying to implement three into an Angular 4 environment, im trying to use a JSONLoader but is not working, i have the path defined to the Json correctly etc but i can´t add it to the scene, "cannot set property "mesh" of undefined on line is the error im getting at the moment

```
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color : 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true });
let geometry = new THREE.JSONLoader();

geometry.load("./maniqui4.json", function(geometry, materials){

this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.scene.add(this.mesh);
});
```

The error is in the line this.scene.add(this.mesh);

i tried adding a Box geometry and it rendered fine, but no way with a JSONLoader

here is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
selector: 'canvasRender',
templateUrl: './canvas.component.html',
})

export class canvasComponent{

@ViewChild('container') elementRef: ElementRef;
private container : HTMLElement;
private scene: THREE.Scene;
private camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
private renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
private mesh : THREE.Mesh;

constructor(){
console.log(THREE);

}

ngOnInit(){
this.container = this.elementRef.nativeElement;

console.log(this.container);

this.init();
}

init(){
let screen = {
  width  : 100,
  height : 300
},
view = {
  angle  : 45,
  aspect : screen.width / screen.height,
  near   : 0.1,
  far    : 1000
};

this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(view.angle, view.aspect, view. near, view.far);
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

this.scene.add(this.camera);
this.camera.position.set(10,10,10);
this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));

this.renderer.setSize(screen.width, screen.height);
this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);


 let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color : 0xFFFFFF, wireframe: true });
 let geometry = new THREE.JSONLoader();

 geometry.load("./maniqui4.json", function(geometry, materials){

this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.scene.add(this.mesh);
});


this.render();
}

render(){

};
animate(){

};

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the line `var scope = this;` at the start of your init() method, like this,

```
init(){ 
    var scope = this;
   // rest of your code

}
```

then change all the references to the `this` with `scope` inside the init() method.

Now the loader will look like this,

```
geometry.load("./maniqui4.json", function(geometry, materials){ 
    scope.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scope.scene.add(scope.mesh); 
});
```

The problem is that when you call `this` from the load function of JsonLoader, you are referring to the JsonLoader itself, not to your canvasComponent class.